# Will adding video memory on ubuntu running on a virtual machine (VM Box) decrease my video memory even when it is not on?

Tags: virtualbox, laptop, gpu-driver

Will putting 128 mb on video memory in VM Box Ubuntu permanently reduce my video memory? Or will it only take effect when the VM machine is on?

Answer (score 0):

It will be used only when the VM is running. All memory available for the host OS otherwise.